# VPN over VPN doesn't work with HTTPS or even some bare HTTP

Tags: networking, vpn

I have the following machines to deal with:

- LOCAL_NAT: a machine that has a connection to the Internet
- LOCAL_WORK: a machine that is networked with LOCAL_1 and accesses the Internet via NAT
- REMOTE_VPN: an IPsec VPN server, accessible over the Internet
- REMOTE_WORK: a server on the remote network

The following setup works: I run a VPN client on LOCAL_WORK that connects to REMOTE_VPN and then I can access REMOTE_WORK.

This doesn't work when I add a fifth machine to my setup:

- VPS: a VPS where another VPN server is running (I've tried IPsec and Wireguard)

I run a VPN client on LOCAL_NAT and can access the Internet via VPS from LOCAL_NAT and LOCAL_WORK, including REMOTE_VPN. I can run a second VPN client on LOCAL_WORK and connect to REMOTE_VPN. However, I cannot connect to REMOTE_WORK from LOCAL_WORK properly. The DNS is resolved correctly, so it looks like I'm using my remote network's VPN server, and I can ping REMOTE_WORK successfully, I can curl an HTTP resource on REMOTE_WORK, but not an HTTPS one. I also can't get anything the page I get via HTTP contains, like CSS or JS files:

```
C:\Users\superuser>curl -vvv --ssl-no-revoke https://REMOTE_WORK
*   Trying ***.***.***.***:443...
* Connected to REMOTE_WORK (***.***.***.***) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

C:\Users\superuser>curl -vvvvv "http://REMOTE_WORK:8000"
*   Trying ***.***.***.***:8000...
* Connected to REMOTE_WORK (***.***.***.***) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: REMOTE_WORK:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sun, 02 Oct 2022 16:29:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 640
< Last-Modified: Thu, 26 May 2022 14:07:40 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "628f89ac-280"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
...
<script src="runtime.bf022b3bbd1bd4e95ec8.js" defer></script>
...
</html>
* Connection #0 to host REMOTE_WORK left intact

C:\Users\superuser>curl -vvvvv "http://REMOTE_WORK:8000/runtime.bf022b3bbd1bd4e95ec8.js"
*   Trying ***.***.***.***:8000...
* Connected to REMOTE_WORK (***.***.***.***) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /runtime.bf022b3bbd1bd4e95ec8.js HTTP/1.1
> Host: REMOTE_WORK:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

What's going on? How can I diagnose this issue further?

Comment: What protocol is running on port 8000? I assume nginx?

Comment: @Ramhound Unsecured HTTP, you can see it in the URL.

Comment: Given that HTTP is typically port 80 not 8000 I am not sure how I was supposed to know that. Which begs the question is HTTPS actually is 443 in your configuration or not. You don’t have to reply to this comment, I won’t be able to help you, I can tell that by the tone of your response to me.